# Close a HTTP Proxy Server

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

I have a little problem with my code, I'm doing a HTTP Proxy Server and I send it a random number of HTTP Request and I want that my program close when I stop of send.
I think the problem is in the accept because the program still working always

I tried to put a recv after the accept for checking if there if empty but the program does't arrive there

My code is the following

```
from socket import *
from _thread import *

MAX_DATA_RECV = 4096    # max number of bytes we receive at once


def start(port_5, my_port):
    s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind(('', my_port))
    s.listen(1)
    while 1:
        try:
            conn, client_addr = s.accept() 
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print('\nProgram closed. Interrupted by the user')
            exit()
        proxy_thread(conn, client_addr)

    s.close()

def proxy_thread(conn, client_addr):

  # get the request from browser
  request = conn.recv(MAX_DATA_RECV).decode('utf-8')

  # parse the first line
  first_line = request.split('n')[0]

  # get url
  url = first_line.split(' ')[1]


  # find the webserver and port
  http_pos = url.find("://")          # find pos of ://
  if (http_pos==-1):
    temp = url
  else:
    temp = url[(http_pos+3):]       # get the rest of url

  port_pos = temp.find(":")           # find the port pos (if any)

  # find end of web server
  webserver_pos = temp.find("/")
  if webserver_pos == -1:
    webserver_pos = len(temp)

  webserver = ""
  port = -1
  if (port_pos==-1 or webserver_pos < port_pos):      # default port
    port = 80
    webserver = temp[:webserver_pos]
  else:       # specific port
    port = int((temp[(port_pos+1):])[:webserver_pos-port_pos-1])
    webserver = temp[:port_pos]

  print("Connect to:", webserver, port)

  # create a socket to connect to the web server
  s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
  s.connect((webserver, port))
  s.send(request.encode())         # send request to webserver
  print(temp)

  while 1:
    # receive data from web server
    data = s.recv(MAX_DATA_RECV)
    if (len(data) > 0):
      # send to browser
      conn.send(data)
    else:
      break
  s.close()
  conn.close()
```

If someone is able to help me, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> I want that my program close when I stop of send

At the network level there is no implicit indicator that the other side will not send anymore. If all requests would be done through a single TCP connection then the end of the connection might be treated as such an indicator.  But you are using a new TCP connection for every request so you need to define your own condition(s) how the server should determine that the client will not send anymore.

This could for example a timeout, i.e. if the client has not sent any more request for 20 seconds then the client is treated as dead. Or it might be a special message by the client to signal the end - in which case your code needs to explicitly look for this message.